# Spiral Traversing Python Turtle

Tags: python, turtle-graphics, python-turtle

I have been trying to solve this for the past few days. It actually works but not in the way I want. The problem is that it starts spiraling from the top left (picture 1) rather than from the bottom right (picture 2), which is what I want. I'm a beginner, and I'm not aware of many of turtle's methods or functions, so please answer my question with your code for better understanding:

```
import turtle
tur=turtle.Turtle()
tur.penup()
tur.setpos(-250,250)
dot_distance=15
def spiral(r,c):
  #r=row,#c=col
  ri=0;ci=0
  #ri=row_index,ci=col_index
  while(ri<r and ci<c):
    
     for i in range(c-1,ci-1,-1):
        tur.dot()
        tur.forward(dot_distance)
        
     r-=1
     tur.right(90)
    
     for i in range(r-1,ri-1,-1):
        tur.dot()
        tur.forward(dot_distance)
        
     ci+=1
     tur.right(90)
    
     for i in range(ci,c):
        tur.dot()
        tur.forward(dot_distance)
        
     ri+=1
     tur.right(90)
    
     for i in range(ri,r):
        tur.dot()
        tur.forward(dot_distance)
        
     c-=1
     tur.right(90)
   
spiral(20,20)
```

Actual output is the 1st picture, but I want it like the 2nd picture, where it starts spiraling from bottom right rather than top left:

[image: ][1]][1]1]

[image: :]

Answer (score 1):

You're just missing [`tur.setheading(180)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/turtle.html#turtle.setheading) after `tur.setpos()`

From the docs:

Set the orientation of the turtle to to_angle: Some common angles in degrees

```
0: East
90: North
180: West
270: South
```

Comment: Thankyou! but i actually am not quite well aware of many of turtle's methods or functions. So, could you also please tell me, where in the program must i place the command which you insist on adding,or it'd be better if you answer me with your modified program code.

Comment: As I said in the answer, put `tur.setheading(180)` after `tur.setpos()`

Answer (score 1):

Simply fixing the starting direction isn't enough, we also need to fix the starting position.  And while we're at it, polish up your code:

```
from turtle import Screen, Turtle

DOT_DISTANCE = 15

def spiral(row, col):

    while col > 0 < row:

        for _ in range(col):
            turtle.forward(DOT_DISTANCE)
            turtle.dot()

        row -= 1
        turtle.right(90)

        for _ in range(row):
            turtle.forward(DOT_DISTANCE)
            turtle.dot()

        col -= 1
        turtle.right(90)

screen = Screen()

turtle = Turtle()
turtle.speed('fastest')  # because I have no patience
turtle.penup()
turtle.setpos(150, -150)
turtle.setheading(180)

spiral(20, 20)

turtle.hideturtle()
screen.exitonclick()
```

Comment: `while col > 0 < row:` that's something I haven't seen before!

Comment: @cdlane thankyou! could you please write the same program to traverse a matrix in spiral form,just for the better understanding of above program.

Answer (score 0):

This code will make a turtle spiral around, leaving a dot trail behind, and the resulting image will be perfectly in the center of the screen:

```
from turtle import Turtle

tur = Turtle()
tur.setheading(180)
tur.penup()
dot_distance = 10

def spiral(r,c):
    tur.setpos(c*dot_distance/2, -r*dot_distance/2)
    r -= 1
    while r+1 and c:
        for _ in range(c):
            tur.forward(dot_distance)
            tur.dot()
        c -= 1
        tur.right(90)
        for _ in range(r):
            tur.forward(dot_distance)
            tur.dot()
        r -= 1
        tur.right(90)
        
spiral(20,20)
```

Output:

[image]

You can see that after each line is drawn, I decrement the variable (`r` or `c`) by 1,
 so this while loop: `while r+1 and c:` tells python that while there are still any dots left for each variable, 
continue drawing lines.